# Extract Mobile (android and IOS) Sensor data via Bluetooth without pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, accelerometer, android-sensors, pairing

I know that connection between two Bluetooth devices can be made without pairing and maybe exchange files. **My question is how can I extract accelerometer data from a smartphone without pairing?** I already have a device that can locate the smartphone  using Bluetooth signals only without connection or pairing. So, I don't have control or access over the smartphone, I only sense its location with a sensor.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Bluetooth BLE (low energy), which doesn’t need pairing, but I’m not sure if you can access accelerometer data without using classic Bluetooth and pairing.

Comment: I just read something called "bluetooth service discovery protocol". It's supposed to tell what I can have access to. I don't know is the access the same for paired connection and unpaired or not. I am not a software developer or engineer.